# i can not install jrebel plugin in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jrebel

intellij idea 14 alter "error in opening zip file" when i install jrebel plugins. 
I have tried Setting -> Browse repositories or used "install from disk", but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please send a screenshot, jrebel.log and jrebel-intellij.log to support@zeroturnaround.com. It would help trouble-shooting the problem a lot.

Comment: You probably downloaded a standalone ZIP archive instead of a plugin distribution? You don't have to download anything yourself, but just install from IntelliJ IDEA plugin repository. Here are the instructions: https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/#!/have-license/intellij

Comment: No I experienced this today as well. After I tried to install from plugin manager. After it downloaded I received an error about not being able to open some zip in the plugins folder. Then when I restarted my IDE the plugins Settings page was blank. I had to completely reinstall. It was very annoying to say the least.